# How to convert String to numerical value in Java

Tags: java, neural-network

I'm working on my Neural Network project, and in data set I have only string values, but I know that NN accepts only numerical values so how can I convert string to double like this :

```
“red” =   0.4582932
“green” = 0.512932
“black” = 0.542123
```

Comment: Use a `Map<String, Double>` to **map** `String` to `Double`.

Comment: Nope , I need represent String value = “black” like bunch off numerical for NN training , but I think I can deal with It , thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the values are dynamic then use the solution that @ElliotFrisch provided in the question comments regarding the use of a Map of type String and Double respectively.

If the values are predetermined and do not change then an enumeration might be the solution for you.

```java
enum Color {
    RED(0.4582932),
    GREEN(0.512932),
    BLACK(0.542123);

    private final double value;

    private Color(double value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

You could then create a Set of the enum values. [ImmutableSet](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/) here.

```java
private static final Set<Color> COLORS = ImmutableSet.copyOf(EnumSet.allOf(Color.class));
```